# How to not iterate dictionary contents when dictionary is in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to iterate different dictionaries in a list and then set the contents of the choosen dictionary as section_choice. But when iterating the dictionaries, it takes the contents of the dictionary. I understand I could just make the dictionary names a string value and then iterate but I want to set section_choice as the dictionary too.

```
dairy = {...}
snacks = {...}

sections = [dairy, snacks]

choice = input("> ")

for i in sections:
    if str(i) == choice:
        section_choice = i
print(section_choice)
```

I tried this and expected `section_choice` to have the same contents as e.g `dairy` but when iterating, `i` is actually the contents of `dairy`.

Comment: Why does your code convert an entire dictionary into a string? I.e. why did you write `if str(i) == choice"`? Remember to name your variables based on what they are, so that when you revisit your code, or you ask someone else to look at it, the code makes sense. In this case, `for section_dict in sections:`, so that the next line reads `if str(section_dict) == choice:` which makes it _super_ obvious that something weird is going on here.

Comment: In that loop, `i` will be `dairy` on the first iteration, and `snacks` on the second iteration.  Assuming you want to check if `choice` is a **key** in the dictionary, you can do `if choice in i:`

Comment: This would be a much better question if you put actual data for `dairy` and `snacks` and `choice`, and you said the actual expected value of `section_choice` at the end.  Otherwise we are just guessing what you want...

Comment: Also, just as a programming style issue, `i` is a terrible variable name in this case because it doesn't give any sort of hint as to what value you _expect_ it to be.  A better name might be something like `food` or `category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above seems correct, but I believe it might be missing a crucial aspect. To determine if the user's choice can act as a key for both the "dairy" and "snacks" dictionaries, you can modify the code as follows:

```py
dairy = {'key_dairy':'value_dairy'}
snacks = {'key_snacks':'value_snacks'}

sections_by_product = {
  "dairy": dairy,
  "snacks": snacks,
}
choice = input("> ")
section_choice = {}

for key in sections_by_product:
    product_by_key = sections_by_product.get(key)
    if choice == key or choice in product_by_key:
        section_choice = product_by_key
        break

print(section_choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `sections` also a dictionary?

```py
sections = {
  "dairy": {...},
  "snacks": {...},
}

choice = input("> ")
section_choice = sections[choice]
print(section_choice)
```